# How do I detect if a user is using my file for the first time?

Tags: python

I'm making a Python file, and I want a different screen to show up for someone who is opening the file for the very first time, other than a recurring visitor. Like so:

```
if USER_NEW:
   print('New user screen')
else:
   print('other screen')
```

Exactly how would I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save program information in a state file. Where to do that depends on the operating system and even then you'll find disagreement. On windows you can use the environment variable `%LOCALAPPDATA%`. On most unixy systems you can use `~/.myapp` or perhaps `~/.config/myapp` (I like the second much better). I don't know the conventions on other machines.

You also need to establish a convention for the format of the file. I'm just going to look for a file name.

```
import platform
import os
import time

if platform.system() == "Windows":
    my_app_path = os.path.expandvars("%LOCALAPPDATA%/myapp")
elif platform.system() == "Linux":
    my_app_path = os.path.expanduser("~/.config/myapp")
else:
    exit(2)

first_run_file = os.path.join(my_app_path, "first_run.txt")
if not os.path.exists(first_run_file):
    first_run = True
    os.makedirs(my_app_path)
    open(first_run_file, "w")
else:
    first_run = False
```

Answer (score 2):

You would need to store the information in another file to read later, when your script is run again.  When you run your script you need to read this file and see if contains a value to say the visitor has already looked at the file or write in it to tell the program when they have during the next visit.

For example:

```
with open('user.txt', 'r+') as file:

    if file.read() == '':
        print('New user screen')
    else:

        print('other screen')
        file.write('visited')
```

Comment: This tells you whether the program has been run in the current local directory before, not whether its been run at all. And there is nothing that says the current directory is writable (lets say its opened by a GUI) so you are limiting the usefulness of your program.